# Performing mass data evaluation using @future

Tags: apex, data, future

I have a use case of creating/updating the records for a custom object based on a specific Account's record type.

Its on the click of a custom button placed over detail page, its working fine for a user with Author Apex permission. We need to check for the user without Author Apex permission, if calling of future method can satisfy our requirement.

As executing the batch for a particular user is giving below error:

[image]

If anyone has any ideas on how I can resolve this, I would be so thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Future methods aren't really intended to bypass user permissions.

Based on the error message, maybe you need to grant acess to the required Apex classes based on the users profiles. See [Setting Apex Class Access from Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_apex_access.htm&language=en_US)

From [Controller Class Security](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_security.htm)

> If you have installed a managed package in your organization, you can set security only for the Apex classes in that package that are declared as global, or for classes that contain methods declared as `webService`.
>   If users have the “Author Apex” permission, they can access all Apex classes in the associated organization, regardless of the security setting for individual classes.